# How do you create a drop down menu with buttons

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to figure out how to create a drop-down list inside of panel, that has buttons in it, like you see in the image for "Mirror". At the moment, I've already figured out how to add a custom button to this panel with the code `bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object_context_menu.append()`, but now I just need to know how to create a drop-down list.

[image]

Comment: these are not buttons, but sub menus. Read here, this should help: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are interested in  `bpy.types.Menu`. Docs: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html#bpy.types.Menu

Here is the example of a code needed to create nested menu you have shown:

```py
import bpy

class MT_NestedMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = "nested.menu"
    bl_label = "Nested Menu"

    # Drawing a nested menu with three operators(buttons)
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator('object.some_operator1', text='Button1')
        layout.operator('object.some_operator2', text='Button2')
        layout.operator('object.some_operator3', text='Button3')

# Defining function to append NestedMenu class to the Object Context Menu
def add_to_view3d_mt_object_context_menu(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.menu('nested.menu', text='Menu')

# Registering/Unregistering
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MT_NestedMenu)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object_context_menu.append(add_to_view3d_mt_object_context_menu)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MT_NestedMenu)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_object_context_menu.remove(add_to_view3d_mt_object_context_menu)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much :)